# If or conditional formula formula in Google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to put conditional formula in spreadsheet using google apps script but i am not getting the way out to resolve this.

The VBA equivalent to the required GAS is:

> Sub ageing()
>
> Rem Ageing Slabs for ADVANCES
>
> With Range("ap2:ap4000")
>
> .Formula = "=IF(u2="""","""",if(u2<0,""Delivery Reported after
> RC"",IF(AND(u2>=0,u2<31),""Ageing
> 0-30"",IF(AND(u2>=31,u2<=60),""Ageing
> 31-60"",IF(AND(u2>=61,u2<=90),""Ageing
> 61-90"",IF(AND(u2>=91,u2<=120),""Ageing
> 91-120"",IF(and(u2>120,u2<=180),""Ageing 121-180"",IF(u2>180,""More
> than 6 months"",""""))))))))"
>
> .Value = .Value
>
> End With
>
> End Sub

Kindly suggest the VBA equivalent to this in GAS.

Thanks

The same question posted on https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/docs/spreadsheets/how-do-i/desktop/H2dXGR7arvU

Comment: That is a very large formula to unwrap. Can you please tell what you are trying to achieve and a solution might arrive quicker

Comment: Thanks for the response, i am trying to put the if condition for a range, which is dependent on the other range. Kindly suggest a way out for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Range.setFormula()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_range#setFormula) to set a formula in a cell.

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().setFormula('=SUM(A1:A100)');
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I think you can make it less complicated by not checking twice for each condition
2. In JS you can put single quotes and double quotes inside it, or " and \" inside.
3. You can use ArrayFormula for this type of tasks, and you can even eliminate Google Apps Script or VBA (it's just one formula in the end)

SpreadsheetApp.getRange("AP2").setFormula('IF(U2:U4000="","",IF(U2:4000<0,"Delivery Reported after RC",IF(U2:U4000<=30,"Ageing 0-30",IF(U2:U4000<=60,"Ageing 31-60",IF(U2:U4000<=90,"Ageing 61-90",IF(U2:U4000<=120,"Ageing 91-120",IF(U2:U4000<=180,"Ageing 121-180","More than 6 months","")))))))');